# $ST$ and $T$ are invertible. Prove that $S$ is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

$(ST)^{-1}$ and $T^{-1}$ exist. So how would I actually show that $S$ is invertible? It seems obvious.

Also just curious, it is true that of $A$ and $B$ are invertible 
then $AB$ is invertible. Is it true that if $AB$ is invertible then $A$ and $B$ are invertible?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

What about

$$ST\circ T^{-1}?$$

Comment: Got it. Since ST and T^(-1) is invertible, S must be invertible. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Short and sweet! +1

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
From Cauchy's theorem we now that
$$
\det (AB) = \det A \cdot \det B
$$

Determinant of invertible matrices is not equal to $0$ or in other words, the matrix is not invertible if and only if the determinant is equal to $0$.  That might help you to answer one of your questions.

Comment: I havent learnt about determinants yet but thanks for answering! I'll come back to it after I've learnt it in the course.

Comment: Well, that's a pitty:). I'll try to think of a different approach then.

Answer (score 1):

If we have proved that $AB$ is invertible if and only if $A$ and $B$ are invertible (supposing $A$ and $B$ are square matrices, say $n\times n$), the invertibility of $S$ when $ST$ and $T$ are invertible follows, because $S=(ST)T^{-1}$.

If $A$ and $B$ are invertible, then $(B^{-1}A^{-1})(AB)=I_n$ (and similarly on the other size), so $AB$ is invertible and $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$.

The converse is not as easy. But we can remember that $A$ is invertible if and only if its rank is $n$. Moreover it's easy to show that
$$
\operatorname{rk}(AB)\le\min\{\operatorname{rk} A,\operatorname{rk} B\}.
$$
Thus $AB$ invertible implies that both $A$ and $B$ have rank $n$, so they are invertible.

For non square matrices it can happen that the product is invertible, but it's known that a non square matrix can't have a two-sided inverse. Example
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}2\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, see the hint in Sami's answer.

Yes, it is always true that if $A,B$ are invertible, then $AB$ is invertible. The inverse of $AB$ is then given by $B^{-1} A^{-1}$. (prove this)

Yes, it is true that if $AB$ is invertible then both $A$ and $B$ are. At least if you assume that both are square of the same size. Then this proof works: $\det(AB)=\det(A) \det(B) \neq 0$.

Comment: I havent learnt about determinants yet. Thanks for your answer though. I was just curious about second part.

Comment: Assuming that $A$ and $B$ are square matrices. The product $AB$ can be invertible without $A$ and $B$ being invertible if they are not square.